# string replace with return statement gives different result. need the clarity

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

**Case 1 :** replace with function return results `j<*zz`

```
const str = 'z<*zj';
const letters = Array.from(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gm, ''));

const result = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/gm, () => letters.pop());
console.log('result', result); // result => j<*zz/
```

**Case 2 :** replace without function return results `j<*jj`

```
const str = 'z<*zj';
const letters = Array.from(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gm, ''));

const result = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/gm,  letters.pop());
console.log('result', result); // result => j<*jj/
```

So, It differs with function integration. what is behind ? Need the help to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#syntax), If a replacement parameter is a `function`, it will be invoked for every match and its return value is used as the replacement text.

Hence, In `case 1` as we are passing `replacement` as an arrow function, it executes for each match and replace with the `letters` array last element. As we are using [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method, It changes the length of the original array and returns the last element.

For example,

```js
const str = 'z<*zj';

const letters = Array.from(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/gm, ''));

console.log(letters.pop()); // j

console.log(letters); // ["z", "z"]
```

In this case, in second iteration it will pop the `z` and replaced with the matched value.

Now if we will talk about the `case 2`, As replacement parameter is a `string`, It will replace the substring matched by pattern in a single go.

For example,

```js
const str = 'z<*zj';

const arr = ['z', 'z', 'j'];

const result = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, arr.pop());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

There exists an overload for `String.prototype.replace` that accepts a function. This function will execute *on every match*. Each match then mutates `letters` via the `pop` method.

When you use `letters.pop()` instead of a method that returns `letters.pop()`, it is only executed once and its result is reused for each match.

Since the last letter in `letters` is `j`, `letters.pop()` evaulates to `j` and each letter is replaced with `j`.

When using the function variant, the last letter is `j`, so the first letter is replaced with `j`, but for subsequent matches, we're now popping from a mutated array, so we then return `z` and finally `z`.